# Sonarqube does not show Android lines of code

Tags: sonarqube

I have multi-module Android/Gradle project. The project has two Java modules and several Android modules. 
I start sonar by runnig the sonarRunner task in the project root. Unfortunatelly the "lines of code", "files", "functions", "complexity" etc. do not include the Android .java files.

The issues (major, minor, blocker, ...) on the other hand are included in the analysis.

Is there a way to include the Android-Java files to the statistics?

Sonarqube version is 4.5.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you should switch and use the new Gradle SonarQube Plugin: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/important-changes-to-gradle-sonarqube-support/10252

Then indeed Android modules are not supported out of the box. Issue was already reported and will be part of next sprint: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-6

Comment: I solved it by applying the sonarRunner-configuration again to the submodules' gradle files.

Comment: Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460191/not-able-to-get-sonarqube-to-index-files-in-my-multi-module-gradle-project.