# Not able to get sonarqube to index files in my multi module gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

I have a multi-module gradle project created in android studio and want to run an analysis using sonarqube. The project structure is as below
root (no source files)
    Module 1
        com.myapp.module1
            package1 
            package2

```
Module 2 (structure similar to that of Module 1)
```

I added the sonarqube plugin in the build.gradle file in root along with the following sonarqube properties: 
a) Host URL
b) jdbc url
c) Username for jdbc
d) password for jdbc

I use gradlew for the build. When I run gradlew sonarqube from my root directory, sonarqube runs but indicates that 0 files are indexed for all the modules.

What am I missing here? It should be something fairly obvious but I have not been able to find an answer in the existing stackoverflow archives.

Comment: Looks like I messed up the formatting when I tried to present the folder hierarcy. To clarify, the root folder does not have any source files. Under each module, I have a set of packages (com.app.,module.package1...) containing the respective java files.

Comment: We do not automatically support Android projects yet in Gradle plugin. So you may have to manually define properties like sonar.sources to have your files correctly indexed.

Comment: Any guidance or pointers on sonar.sources? I tried the following that did not work: sonar.sources=android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs

Comment: Ok - got it working. I had to set sonar.sources under each of my module. Maybe a beginner's error. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I had to explicitly have sonar.sources property in each of the module.

`sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.sources"] += "src"
    }`
}

Comment: Does it work if you configure it once in the root project using `subprojects` statement?
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle#AnalyzingwithGradle-Sharedconfigurationsettings

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to put sonar.sources in each module

**Check my answer in this link,it worked for me:**

[What is the correct way to configure an Android project with submodules for use with the sonarqube gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438282/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-an-android-project-with-submodules-for-use/43384294#43384294)