# What is the correct way to configure an Android project with submodules for use with the sonarqube gradle plugin?

Tags: android, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

What is the correct way to configure an Android project with submodules for use with the sonarqube gradle plugin?  Google has not been my friend, but I may have missed something basic.  (I search for sonarqube issues related to the android build directories and submodules.  No useful results.)

At a very high level, I am working with an Android project with the following structure.

```
git_repository
|----- android_project
  |--- app
  |--- SDK
    |- api
```

The git_repository contains the README.md and other top level files including the android_project.  The android_project contains the the app, as well as a git submodule in SDK.  This git submodules contains the api code that app needs to run.

The problem is that when I try to run sonarqube, it seems to be looking for files/directories that do not exist.  I do not have this problem with a simpler minimal project.  I plan to set up a minimal project that uses submodules on Monday, but I want to get this question out the door before I leave for the weekend.

```
$ ./gradlew clean sonarqube
* snip *
:sonarqube
Invalid value for sonar.java.test.libraries
:sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> No files nor directories matching '/Users/my_username/git_repository/android_project/app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.897 secs
$
```

This gradle task is fail on a MacOS/Android Studio command line setup, but the ultimate goal is to have a configuration that works with Jenkins. 
My settings.gradle and build.gradle files follow.  Clearly I am doing something wrong.

**git_repository/android_project/settings.gradle** complete listing

```
include ':app', ':api'
project(':api').projectDir = new File('SDK/api')
```

**git_repository/android_project/build.gradle** complete listing

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}

//subprojects {
//    sonarqube {
//        properties {
// //           property "sonar.sources", "src"
//        }
//    }
//}

//sonarqube {
//    properties {
////        property "sonar.exclusions", "file:**/SDK/**"
//    }
//}

subprojects {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.sourceEncoding","UTF-8"
            property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
            property "sonar.java.binaries", "./build/"
            property "sonar.tests","src/androidTest"
//            property "sonar.exclusions","build,build/**,**/*.png"

            property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true

            property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
        }
    }
}

project(":api") {
    sonarqube {
        skipProject = true
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont u use sonarqube as software for specific machine rather then use it as gradle plugin

Answer (score 2):

yes its a bit tricky for a project with multiple modules,its achieved using proper wildcards.

follow these steps:

1. in the master module which contains all the sub-modules place the
   **sonarqube.gradle** file
   [image]
2. in the build.gradle file of the master module add the maven plugin and
   class dependencies 
   [image]

here is an example of two above mentioned files:

**sonarqube.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    properties {
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.projectName", "appar"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.analysis.mode", "publish"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.language", "java"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property 'sonar.sourceEncoding', "UTF-8"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.sources", "./src/main"
   // noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.exclusions", "src/main/java/com/appar/model/**, **/*Entity.java"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://192.168.21.33:9000"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.login", "admin"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.profile", "fulllint"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property 'sonar.import_unknown_files', true
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.password", "admin"
 //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/"

    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

then apply from sonarqube.gradle in build.gradle of separate modules

here is an example of build.gradle of one of the sub modules:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../sonarqube.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':java-library')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.4"
}
```

just put this line along with all other apply lines as shown in the above file

```
apply from: '../sonarqube.gradle'
```

[image]

after you apply sonarqube.gradle to all the build.gradle files in the sub modules.

just run the command

```
./gradlew sonarqube
```

trust me the project will successfully get build and get pushed into sonarqube server and the error results will get shown

if you are using findbugs make the project before pushing or else build will fail because the findbugs needs the bytecode to analyse.

And dont use the property

```
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            property "sonar.projectKey", "appar_app"
```

This sonar.projectKey property. This is used by SonarQube to identify each project (or module) in sonar database.
So if all your modules have same projectKey value, SonarQube will update one single project in its database.
Don't worry, this property is automatically set with the folder name of each module.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

I am gettin gthis error while running gradlew sonarqube.

Comment: @Amal p: this does not work, it uploads logs for only one module which is the last one. Which means it overwrites the logs of previous modules