# Gradle task to aggregate checkstyle reports in a multi module project

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I have a multi module gradle project having the following structure:

```
myProject
|
|-module1
  |-src
    |-main
    |-test
  |-build.gradle
|-module2
  |-src
    |-main
    |-test
  |-build.gradle
|-build.gradle
```

I have the following configurations to generate checkstyle report:

```
checkstyle {
        toolVersion = '6.4.1'
        configFile = rootProject.file("config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml");
        showViolations = true
        ignoreFailures = true
        reportsDir = file("$project.rootDir/reports/checkstyle/$project.name")
        tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
            reports {
                xml.enabled true
                html.enabled true
            }
        }
    }

checkstyleMain << {
        ant.xslt(in: file("$project.rootDir/reports/checkstyle/$project.name/main.xml"),
                style: rootProject.file('config/checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl'),
                out: rootProject.file('config/aggregated.html'))
    }
```

My aim to generate an aggregated checkstyle report that contains information from both these two modules. When I run *"gradle checkstyleMain"* the aggregated html report contains only checkstyle report information from module2 and ignores module1 information.

I am new to gradle it will be great if someone can help me out. Please let me know if you need additional information

Answer (score 0):

Try including your configurations to generate checkstyle report

in the build.gradle files of each module seprately instead of including this 
only on your projects build.gradle file.

---

Or you can use this plugin

Download link -  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea

it gives proper results

---

Or use sonarqube -And refer my answer in the link below

[What is the correct way to configure an Android project with submodules for use with the sonarqube gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438282/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-an-android-project-with-submodules-for-use/43384294#43384294)

just sharing my opinion hope it helps.