# Sonarqube exclusion for multi-module maven project

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a multi-module maven project. In my parent pom, it is like this -

```
<modules> 
    <module>a</module> 
    <module>b</module> 
    <module>c</module> 
</modules>
```

I want to scan a & b's src/main/java but c is having a different structure like this: c/src/main/dir1/dir2/dir3/js1 & c/src/main/dir1/dir2/dir4/js2
I want to scan project c till dir3 but exclued dir4

It has become complex and I don't know what to include and exclude. I am using maven scanner and passing parameter in sonarqube plugin in jenkins as parameters like this:

```
-Dsonar.projectName="MyProject" -Dsonar.sources="." -Dsonar.projectKey="MyKey" -Dsonar.inclusions="src/main/java/**,c/src/main/dir1/dir2/**" -Dsonar.exclusions="c/src/main/dir1/dir2/dir3" -Dsonar.scm.disabled=true -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I have tried making it modular also using sonar.modules, but the excluding of the required directories is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using the maven scanner, then `mvn sonar:sonar` is all you need, you don't need to specify `-Dsonar.sources=...` and probably none of the other `-D` parameters in your example. That is the whole point of the maven scanner, it understands your maven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**The below answer is just a suggestion for you**....

Don't use `sonar.modules` property

check out my answer in the below link

[What is the correct way to configure an Android project with submodules for use with the sonarqube gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438282/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-an-android-project-with-submodules-for-use/43384294#43384294)

And configure exclusions in the sonarqube.gradle file of each module separately using the property

```
 // noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.exclusions", "src/main/java/com/appar/model/**, **/*Entity.java"
```

This will solve your problem.